# Anime where the main character's brother sacrifices himself by driving a missile or ship to its explosion

Tags: story-identification, anime

Please help me identify an anime which I forgot the name of. All
I can remember is a scene about the brother of the main character sacrificing himself by driving a missile or ship to a place in order to explode, and a woman trying to stop him but he locks the door. She tries to identify him by saying, "Are such and such?" but he doesn't reply, then she leans on the door and starts crying, as he replies "Take care," or something to that extent.

- It was in Japanese, subtitled in English
- I don't remember the year exactly but I'm sure it's not before 2005
- The setting was in a spaceship (It's not *Spaceship Yamato*)

Comment: Can you clarify the fantasy or science fiction aspects of this show?

Comment: Also, can you go to https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info and see if those prompts give you more details that you can edit into your question?

Comment: Could you please edit your post and add further details? From what time is that anime and when did you watch it? In what language? how did the characters look like?

Comment: Some of these details fit the death of Kittan in Tengen Toppa Gurren Lagann (set on a spaceship, a man who's like a brother to the main character driving a ship to make it explode, a goodbye like "Take care" and a woman crying), but there's no scene with a door locking or dialog that goes "Are you such and such?" so I'm hesitant to suggest it as an answer.

Comment: no its not tengen toppa....its involved spaceship but not a robot fighting

Answer (score 1):

I do recall an episode of trigun where the main character (bash) has a brother (knives), the ship is heading to crash in to a planet and the officer (also mentor of the brothers) initially try to step out the ship, but the girl stay behind to stop the ship and allow the lots of people to survive.

Comment: no its not trigun .......its in the 2005 and up